# hibernate left join lazycollection untouchable

Tags: java, hibernate

I got something like this:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Parent.class,"p");
parentsList = crit.createCriteria(
    "childSet","c",
    JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN,
    Restrictions.eq("jt.2ndParentDto.pk2ndParentDto", pk2ndParent))
    .list();
```

My query returns a list of parents with one child each or none, i already tested the logged query directly, so i am pretty sure of it.

I have to retrieve a list of children, so i am adding the parent and creating the ones missing.

```
List<ChildDto> list=new ArrayList<ChildDto>();
for(ParentDto item:parentsList){
    Iterator<ChildDto> it=item.getChildSet().iterator();
    if(it.hasNext()){
        ChildDto dto = it.next();
        dto.setParentDto(item);
        list.add(dto);
    }
    else{
        ChildDto dto = new ChildDto();
        dto.setParentDto(item);
        list.add(dto);
    }
}
return list;
```

By calling `item.getChildSet().iterator()` hibernate loads the entire collection so i cannot call `item.getChildSet().iterator().hasNext` to check if there is something in the set, and i cannot call `item.getChildSet().size()` neither for the exact same reason...

then how?, what else is there?, i am currently out of ideas, how can i get the only item of the set if there is one?

**Update**: I just tried Extra lazy loading, but it doesn't change for better or worse...

`item.getChildSet().iterator()` still causes to load the entire collection.

And when i do `item.getChildSet().size()` hibernate triggers a count... so i always get size of the entire collection (no use).

And that's pretty much it =/

**Update**: I got it working with a projection by getting a list of Object[] items, and manually creating the classes.
I don't like to do this because, with a change to the Hbm, you're forced to maintain queries of this kind, so i try to avoid this as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking, but I think you're looking for Hibernate ["extra lazy"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching) collections, which allow you to get some information about a collection, including the size, without initializing the entire collection, as well as load large collections into memory in batches, rather than all at once.

Comment: Its a problem related to passing objects from two diferent frameworks, i cant not send a lazycollection from one languaje to another, the heavy reflection causes to load everything from the db, but i can send proxy objects, so in my example i am building a list of children with his parent, but i cant even get the parents out of the sets... (untouchable).
Trying the Extra lazy fetching, lets see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the query to return the child records instead? That way you won't get the whole collection. I am not begin clear. Can you just get the child objects from the database, then call something like getParent() to get the parents you need?

Comment: hmm, i think that triggers n+1 queries, but yeah, that works too. Currently, is the only way i know to navigate through entities and is the reason why made this question, i don't know how to interact with lazy collections without fully loading them...

Comment: That and the projection approach (which is a less maintainable code).